# Use python to parse a log file and print to LCD using GPIO on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, parsing, lcd, gpio

I am new to python so please forgive me in advance ;-) I am trying parse a log file for a name that always occurs after a known word and print that name to an LCD using the GPIO library. I have the LCD working and can print a given message but not sure how to use python to grep the log file and output that information to the LCD. Any help would be great, thanks...

Comment: It is unlikely (I hope) that you will get a canned answer for this at SO. My suggestion would be to read about [File Objects](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects), [String Operations](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html), and [Regular Expression Operations](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html) in Python first. Then try to come up with a solution based on this knowledge. If you get in trouble, post specific code and error messages here.